# Matrix size in Python

Tags: python, variables, matrix, size

**a** is a 2x2 matrix

**b** is a 2x1 matrix

**c** is a 1x2 matrix

But ... what kind of matrices **d** is?

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b= np.array([[1],[2]])
c= np.array([[1,2]])
d= np.array([1,2])
```

[Variable explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09HZD.png)

Comment: A 1 dimensional matrix with two elements in it, you can simply check the shape of an array with `d.shape`, which gives `(2,)`. This its telling you that it has `2` elements in its first and only axis

Comment: Its an array or if you want to keep with the nomenclature a row vector

Comment: Did my answer below resolve the question you had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `d` is not a matrix but a row vector.

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b= np.array([[1],[2]])
c= np.array([[1,2]])
d= np.array([1,2])

print(a.shape, b.shape, c.shape, d.shape)
print(a.ndim, b.ndim, c.ndim, d.ndim)
```

outputs shapes:

```
(2, 2) (2, 1) (1, 2) (2,)
```

and dimensions:

```
2 2 2 1
```

The number of brackets indicate the number of dimensions, for example:

```
e = np.array([[[1,2]]])
```

outputs `shape` `(1, 1, 2)` and `ndim` `3` (so 3 dimensional).

Comment: In this case, what is the difference between c and d, I think c is also a row vector?   (a row vector or row matrix is a 1 × m matrix)

Comment: The number of brackets indicate the dimensions. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 1-dimensional array with 2 elements in it.

Check the output in the [sandbox](https://codidate.com/code/sandbox?s=p3c97wdavw).